undetectable Dart-Input in Visual Code Studio
I made a script in in Visual Studio Code using Dart that grabs the user's input.
The problem is, that if I enter something in the input line in vscode, which is located below the debug console and press enter, nothing happens.
import 'dart:io'

void main() {
  print("testing space\n-------------------");

  String? s = stdin.readLineSync();

  print(s);
}

I did more research (I didn't). I haven't found anything to this problem yet except for using the terminal

The debug console does not accept user input. Try running your program in the terminal (the tab on the right):
$ dart main.dart
testing space
-------------------
hi
hi

