Can't input to Console
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var a = stdin.readLineSync();
  print(a);
}

My code always returns null value. I can't type anything into console.
Note: ! or ? doesn't change output. My variable always gets null value automaticaly and doesn't let me type.
Thanks for help!


I have checked flutter doctor, OK.
I have checked system variables PATH, OK:
I have created same project on flutlab.io and downloaded it. I opened it on my computer and (console) worked. If I create project in my computer console doesn't work. I can't pass value via console, it acts like I have pressed enter without type anything and gets null beacuse of that.

I can't type anything but when I press enter it says "Read-only"

Studio always makes me select a Device, can't even run simplest code without starting emulator as well. (Problem might be about it?)

try in a different environment (IDE).

Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78689170/12507984

I am using Android Studio not VSCode. Uploaded screenshots for clearance.
